# How to use cdk-virtual-scroll with ngx-infinite-scroll

Tags: angular, virtualization, infinite-scroll, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I've upgraded my Angular project dependencies:

- @angular/core: ^14.2.9
- @angular/cdk: ^14.2.9
- @angular/material: ^14.2.6
- ngx-infinite-scroll: ~14.0.1

And after that, the infinite scroll (with virtualization) stopped working.

What I observed is that the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` does not add a scroll anymore if the `scrollWindow` property is set to `false` and the `ngx-infinite-scroll` needs that property to be set to `false`.

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
  *ngIf="items.length"
  class="virtualScrollViewport"
  itemSize="80"
  minBufferPx="400"
  maxBufferPx="600"
  infiniteScroll
  [infiniteScrollDistance]="1"
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
  [infiniteScrollDisabled]="loading || !loaded || !canLoadMoreItems"
  [scrollWindow]="false"
  (scrolled)="onScroll()"
>
  <div><p class="text-bold">Available items</p></div>
  <mat-card *cdkVirtualFor="let itemof items; trackBy: trackByFunction">
    <mat-card-content>
      ...
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>

  <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading && items?.length" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Now the scroll is not displayed anymore (`.cdk-virtual-scrollable` class is not added anymore). Without the `[scrollWindow]="false"` it is, but the infinite scroll is not working because based on their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll?activeTab=readme) this property is necessary. So, these two things go head to head.

Has anyone faced the same issue and found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport)


 set scrollEvent(scrollRef: CdkVirtualScrollViewport) {if (scrollRef) {
  if (
    //note: scrolled container size must be greater than 0, we have to scroll from the top and bottom must have an offset smaller than 50 to trigger
    scrollRef.measureRenderedContentSize() > 0 &&
    scrollRef.measureScrollOffset("top") !== 0 &&
    scrollRef.measureScrollOffset("bottom") < 50
  ) {
    this.scrolled.emit();
  }
} }
```

I just have the same problem and I came up with a workaround. So You can listen to the scroll event by Yourself and add Your own rule of scroll event display. So in my case, I check if the element has height, we start scrolling from the top, and if the bottom is at least 50px. This works but I am still looking for a better solution.